# VisualC++ function problems (and other)

Tags: c++

I have programmed in C++ a while, and I thought It would be fun to try to start with Visual C++ and make a calculator.

Okay, so I have designed at simple window, with two Textboxes, and one button that Adds the two boxes together.
I do know that I dont need a function for this, but I like to try things out, to learn them.
So when Im in the design view, I doubleclick on the button, to get to its code.
In the start of the code, I made two variables, and assigned a value to them.
Now I would like to call a function that takes two parameters and returns the added value.
Thats where it gets annoying, because I get this error:

```
 error C3861: 'addFunction': identifier not found
```

I also have another problem.
I have an if() to make sure that both textboxes have a value.
The if is like this:

```
if(a && b)
```

The compiler gives me this error:

```
error C2676: binary '&&' : 'std::string' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Yeah, one of the variables is a string, but it should still work, right?

I HOpe you can help me!

**EDIT** 
I have solved these two problems, but now, some more occured.

The one error is complaining about this:

```
textstring = DecryptedBox->Text;
```

And there is another error, occuring in the compiler log like 10 times

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\xstring(707): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator =(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
```

What does it mean?

Comment: post some code... and also mention the file structure..

Comment: If you have solved your problems you should vote up the answers that were useful, and accept the answer that has helped you the most.  Then you should post a new question about your new problem.

Comment: Okay then. I will make a new Question for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assumming that string a && b  are both string values.  So you should do something like

```
if(a.empty() || b.empty())
    std::cout << "Values don't exist in one of the boxes" << std::endl;
```

And the addFunction identifier not found means that the compiler cannot find the addFunction function.  Did you declare it? Is it in another class and you didn't do an include?

Comment: `empty` is a function. You need empty parentheses on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use a string with `&&`. It is a logical operator. The parameters must convert to boolean. You can try :

```
if((a != "") && (b != ""))
```

Assuming that a and b are string initialized to the empty string.

For your `addFunction` problem, not enough details ...

my2c

Comment: FWIW, when combining expressions in an `if` statement, extra parenthesis aids in reading.  Prefer: `if ((a != "") && (b != ""))`, this provides extra insurance that readers (and coders) will not misunderstand the statement.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't defined "addFunction". You've probably spelled it wrong.

To check whether a string is empty or not, just check if its size is > 0. So your code should become:

```
if(a.size() && b.size())
```

Comment: Hey. Have you tested it out on
system::String?
It gives me compiler error:
error C2039: 'Size' : is not a member of 'System::String'

Comment: This is meant to work with std::string, not System::String. Anyway, try "size" in lowercase, just in case.

Comment: I have, and it didn't work. Can you tell me if there is another way of getting the lenght?

Comment: The way to get the length of a string is the size() method. You must be doing something wrong. Have you included <string> ? Remember that C++ is case-sensitive, and STL classes' names are composed by lower-case letters. So in this case, "a" and "b" must be std::string, and the method to be called is a.size() for example.

Answer (score 1):

For the error in the `if(a && b)` statement, you are probably mistakenly assuming that `a` and `b` are c-style `char *`, and you are trying to check them for being `NULL`.  However, the reality seems to be that `a` and `b` are objects of class `std::string`, which are not convertible to booleans.  You can check if an `std::string` is empty by using the `empty()` member function.  Or you check if it is equal to `""`.

For the undefined function error, check if you are including the header where the function is defined, and that you have the right namespace.